# Viewstate corruption with VS2010 Web Performance Tests

Tags: visual-studio-2010, viewstate, webtest

When running one of my Visual Studio web performance tests, I noticed intermittent exceptions when trying to decode viewstate:

**Message:** Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.

**Call Stack:** at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState) at System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()

This only happens on one test at a single spot.  Doing some research I noticed that the viewstate sent by the client and the viewstate received by the server differed only in that all plus (`+`) characters became spaces ( ).

What is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET expects that the `_VIEWSTATE` hidden form field is URL-encoded before it reaches the server.  When ASP.NET receives a request, it URL-decodes the `_VIEWSTATE` parameter, which is known to turn pluses into spaces.

Setting the **URL Encode** property to **true** on the `_VIEWSTATE` hidden form field  in the webtest caused the bug to go away.